# Пытаюсь загрузить своего тг бота написанного на aiogram на хостинг pythonanywhere. Помогите пожалуйста. Выдает ошибку:

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 992, in _wrap_create_connection return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection raise exceptions[0] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection sock = await self._connect_sock( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock await self.sock_connect(sock, address) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect return await fut File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 505, in _sock_connect sock.connect(address) OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 170, in make_request async with session.post( File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1194, in aenter self._resp = await self._coro File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 578, in _request conn = await self._connector.connect( File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 544, in connect proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout) File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 911, in _create_connection _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout) File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1235, in _create_direct_connection raise last_exc File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1204, in _create_direct_connection transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection( File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1000, in _wrap_create_connection raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/Neo228/Bot/settings.py", line 202, in asyncio.run(dp.start_polling(bot)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run return loop.run_until_complete(main) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete return future.result() File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 551, in start_polling await asyncio.gather(*done) File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 340, in _polling user: User = await bot.me() File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 364, in me self._me = await self.get_me() File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 1823, in get_me return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout) File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/bot.py", line 492, in call return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout) File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/base.py", line 254, in call return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method)) File "/home/Neo228/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/client/session/aiohttp.py", line 177, in make_request raise TelegramNetworkError(method=method, message=f"{type(e).name}: {e}") aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: HTTP Client says - ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]

Comment: Ну забанен там телеграм. Вроде известная проблема. На всех халявных хостингах так.